# Osherove's naming conventions for parameterized unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, naming-conventions, parameterized-unit-test

Roy Osherove in his book "The Art of unit testing" indicates a good tone naming test, but it is at odds with parameterized tests about which he mentions only in passing.
Parameterized test easier to write, in some aspects, and read. But there are also negative aspects:

- Harder to debug a specific set of parameters;
- More difficult to understand what exactly checks the test, since parameters can for themselves not to talk.

Interested somebody decides for himself the issue. And what conclusions reached. Is it right to sacrifice your points for the sake of speed writing tests?